# Is there a remote file transfer solution for TextMate?

Tags: textmate, ftp

Currently doing some php in Eclipse but want to switch to something like Textmate because Eclipse runs like a fat dog. Eclipse has Esftp installed as well as subclipse. This way when i want to work on a new project, I connect to the SVN server and fetch the project from there. The project then has all the configuration already set for esftp most of the time so that you can just save changes to the server directly.

My question is can if I can assign a rootfolder for the project on a remote server as well after I've imported the project from SVN? So I can just upload changes to the server directly?

Comment: There are multiple bundles available that provide FTP uploading functionality. Have you looked at those?

Comment: Yes I have. It's not that I didn't know there are FTP plugins out there. It's just about this specific thing I want to do.

Comment: Not a transfer solution so not posting this as an answer, but [rmate (a TextMate built-in feature)](http://erniemiller.org/2011/12/12/textmate-2-rmate-awesome/) allows you to edit files on the remote server directly over SSH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While TextMate doesn't have built-in FTP or SSH capabilities there are a few bundles for it that have tried to remedy this shortcoming.

In particular the [FTP/SSH Bundle](http://fuerstnet.de/ftp-ssh-bundle-textmate) aims to provide what you seek: a way to define a "project" that can be synchronized (both up and down) with a remote file system. The bundle is a touch dangerous if you're using FTP as it requires your password be left in plaintext in the `.ftpssh_settings` file that you leave on disk at the root of your project folder to tell the plugin how to connect to your remote file system.

The other option, if you're not set on TextMate and just want something *like* TextMate, is to take a look at [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/). I'll be honest, I was a die hard TextMate guy, but in the last six weeks Sublime Text 2 has won me over. The active development from the company on the product, the *very* active bundle community, and it's incredible speed when it comes to working on large files have really taken me in. There's an [FTP, FTPS, SFTP plugin](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) for ST2 that's a cut above the plugin for TM I mentioned above. It leverages keychain for password storage and doesn't require you keep your passwords in plaintext on disk for it to work. It also lets you set up mappings for remote <-> local connections directly from the editor UI.

Comment: I downloaded sublime text when you posted this and started looking at it sporadically. Looks pretty cool. Now I am very aware that there are many IDE's with svn and ftp integration. But there is something specific about the workflow at my job that I need to be able to do. I'll update my question to try to make it more clear

Comment: As far as I can tell, Sublime Text's dev has come to a halting crawl. ST3 isn't even out yet and it's been a long long time since it started. I'm kinda disappointed in it's development and progress. I'm waiting for Lime to come out.